# Symbol selector cannot be resized

Tags: qgis, symbology, gui, windows-8

[image]

I recently use QGIS 3.0.0, in Windows 8. Today, I work with symbol. When I use SVG symbol, the symbol selector window become so long, even under the taskbar, I cannot resize or drag up the window (it won't allow me). No, it's not just covered by taskbar, it's under the monitor boundary.

Previously I used QGIS 2.18 .12 and never met this problem.

Maybe this is just silly question, but I need help.

Comment: Same problem here, and I can't tab through to the confirmation button.

Comment: I have the same problem. Using QGIS 3.4.1 in Windows 10 Home ed.

Answer (score 2):

**RESOLVED: The dev version 3.5 has resolved this issue (2018-11-18), so expect to see it come in the next full release.**

This is definitely not a silly question, and a real issue for users of small screens.  I'm running QGIS 3.2.3 on Windows 10, 14-inch laptop with a max resolution of 1366x768, and have the same problem.  It's already been reported as [QGIS Issue #18872](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18872), but adding more reports to the bug tracker can only help escalate the issue.

Fortunately, there is a workaround, even if it's an odd workflow.  As noted in the issue report, instead of using Single-symbol or categorized, switch over to "rule-based" and it uses a different dialog that is resizable.